# Getting PUT data in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, dingo-api

I'm struggling to create working PUT routes in my Lumen API. My requests reach the correct route, but I'm unable to access any values through `$request->all()`.

I've figured out that PHP needs to read the `php://input` stream to get the PUT body. This is done in the `getContent()` function of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`. However, this function is called multiple times and since the input buffer is emptied when read, the data is not present when I need it.

I also found out that when I set my Content-Type header to text/plain I can successfully print `$request->json()`, but when I set it to application/json the object is empty.

Any ideas?

PS: I'm aware that for HTML requests you should add the _method parameter, but since I'm not doing my requests through HTML the parameter shouldn't be needed.

**Edit:**

My route:

```
$app->put('settings', 'SettingController@update');
```

My controller:

```
class SettingController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Which part? In my routes.php: `$api->put('settings', 'SettingController@update');`. In the update method I simply do `print_r($request->all())`, which is empty. I'm using the dingo package by the way.

Comment: Show your route and controller if you're using one.

Comment: I edited my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this exact same problem with Lumen. In public/index.php I had to replace:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();

$app->run($request)
```

with this:

```
$app->run();
```

**Note:**
If you want to use the Request object after $app->run() (for example to do some logging or benchmarking) you should use $app->request.

```
logging_function($app->request);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Not sure why I had `Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();` in the first place, but anyway

Answer (score 1):

The Content-Type of your request needs to be set accordingly.
In my case i was sending json data, so ive set it to application/json.

So when i sent this in my request body:

```
{"asd": "asdf"}
```

I got this response with the  code from your controller:

```
Array
(
    [asd] => asdf
)
```

Comment: Well that is the weird thing: when I set the Content-Type to application/json the response is empty. When I set it to text/plain, though, and output `$request->json()`, the correct data is outputted. Could it have something to do with the dingo API package?

Comment: Ok we figured out dingo was not the problem; when turned off the request object is still initiated twice

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the correct content type in your header. try

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```